Symlink from snap package points to a different file than as described by `ls -l`
Recently I installed the tradingview snap package, and I wanted to add some launch flags so I decided to inspect the package. Opening the tradingview_tradingview.desktop file shows that it executes a symlink at /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/tradingview. However when I run ls -l /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/tradingview, it returns
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr  5 15:09 /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/tradingview -> /usr/bin/snap

This is a bit confusing. If I execute the command manually in the command line, substituting /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/tradingview for /usr/bin/snap, nothing happens, and the snap help menu is displayed. However if I execute /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/tradingview, the tradingview app is opened. Does anybody know whats going on here?

Programs can inspect what name they were called with and adjust their behavior accordingly.  For example, pkill and pgrep are usually the same binary.  I expect if you dig into how snap is designed you'll find details about this.
